# Why doesn't backgrounding and re-opening an app call viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers, vc1 and vc2. A modal segue is invoked from vc1 when I want to load vc2. Say I background the app when vc2 is showing. Why isn't viewDidAppear called when the app is re-opened to the view that was left off? How else am I able to detect every time vc2 appears?

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` is not called when the app returns to the foreground because the view controller has already been displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` in VC2 and call `viewDidAppear` from there. Do this in your `viewDidLoad` of VC2:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                     selector:@selector(somethingThatWillCallViewDidAppear:)
                       name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
                                  object:nil];
```

As rmaddy says below, make sure to remove the observer in dealloc or viewDidUnload.

Comment: Also you forgot to add "name:" right before UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Comment: Also make sure you remove the observer in the `dealloc` method. Also keep in mind that you should not call `viewWillAppear:` yourself. Refactor code from `viewWillAppear:` that you want to call from both `viewWillAppear:` and the notification handler.

Comment: Depending on your real need, it may be more appropriate to register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` instead.

Comment: @rmaddy If I'm using ARC I don't have to have to remove the observer right?

Comment: ARC has nothing to do with it. If you add an observer then you must remove the observer. If you don't your app will likely crash if a notification is sent to an observer that has been deallocated. From the docs for `NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:` - *Be sure to invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before notificationObserver or any object specified in addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.*

Comment: Yeap, he's right. That's why they left the `dealloc` method in, so you can clean up those sorts of things.